AWS DMS subscription SNS filter on body message
I'm looking to filter some DMS Event ID from an SNS subscription. They doesn't have attribute so I'm looking to using a filter on the body.
I was trying something like this it didn't seem to work (on a lambda subscription I don't have event anymore, on a SQS one I have all of them ...):
{
  "Event ID": [
    {"anything-but": ["DMS-EVENT-0091", "DMS-EVENT-0093"]}
  ]
}

Can someone give me some guidance about it?
Thanks
